# Unable to query StandardFlowfileRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi Everyone **I'm trying to get the total number of rows all the files I'm collecting that I calculated using QueryRecord in the pipeline as follows but I get errors.
GetFile-->CountText-->ReplaceText-->MergeContent-->QueryRecord
this is error, this error is in processor QueryRecord.Can Someone help me.**

```
 QueryRecord[id=d2555423-0179-1000-01c5-69175e4b54cc] Unable to query StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=96594164-f103-4d34-949a-2c5a50b9aa00,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1622787564383-4, container=default, section=4], offset=27694, length=2],offset=0,name=location.csv,size=2] due to
    java.sql.SQLException:Error while preparing statement [SELECT SUM(cnt) as cnt FROM FLOWFILE]
    org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException:Error while preparing statement [SELECT SUM(cnt) as cnt FROM FLOWFILE]
    [QueryRecordProcessor][1]
```

Comment: Is there anything more in the logs when that happens? Sometimes there's a "Caused by" underneath that gives more details as to what went wrong. Also what version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: I use NiFi-1.12.1, I wanted to attach images but the images do not load properly.

Comment: Hi @mattyb, for more detail you can see here https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Nifi-QueryRecord-Error/m-p/317696#M227281, I couldn't add the images so I posted on my cloudera account.

Comment: `Schema Text` property value of Controller Service has `$`, can you please try just by removing that character. Also what  if you add `CountText` after `MergeContent` this will still provide you various metrics for merged flowfile.

Comment: Please refer to this for example schema definition - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.csv.CSVReader/additionalDetails.html